# $\newcommand{\R} {\mathbb R}$ Why can't an immersed submanifold of $\R^2$ have an isolated point?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I'm doing problem 5-10 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds:
$\newcommand{\R} {\mathbb R}$
Let $M_a= \{(x,y) \in \R^2 | y^2 = x(x-1)(x-a) \} \subset \R^2$

For which values of a is $M_a$ an embedded submanifold of $\R^2$? For which
values can $M_a$ be given a topology and smooth structure making it into an
immersed submanifold? I've shown that for all $a \neq 0,1$, $M_a$ is an embedded submanifold and that  $M_1$ can be made into an immersed submanifold.

This might be trivial, but I wanted to ask why $M_0 = \{(x,y) | x^2(x-1)=y^2\}$ cannot be made into an immersed submanifold of $\R^2$. It is clear from the graph that $(0,0)$ is an isolated point (in the subspace topology). However, how can I prove that there is no topology or smooth structure that can make $M_0$ into an immersed submanifold of $\R^2$? Whenever I try to prove this, I end up assuming something about the topology of $M_0$.

Comment: Note that my definition of a manifold includes the stipulation that it has a specific, well-defined dimension (see the paragraph in the middle of page 3).

Comment: I see, so since M_0 is the disjoint union of a curve and a point, its dimension is not well-defined and by Theorem 1.2, neighbourhoods of a point (0,0) cannot be homoeorphic to open intervals in R